# in-app purchases with refund in wp8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I developed application searching information about numbers in the server database. Sometimes there is no information about some number. Now my client wants to add new functionality.

Imagine this user story: User ask information about number XXX. The server has no information about number XXX. The application tells user about it and offer him to order human handled search on an individual basis. He orders it. After while client's staff tries to find information about number XXX.

If they found it, the User should get push notification and can view the results about number XXX.

If they didn't find, the User should receive a full refund.

Each possible number XXX requires different purchases.

Instead of buy-refund can be hold-release-cancel.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, certainly... By the way: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The store doesn't over refunding. All sales are final.
could you just get the info and not display it until they paid? Ie "we have the info you requested - click here to pay for it and receive it".

Comment: No, I can't do it this way, because, for example, user will be able to ask hundreds of numbers just for fun and pay only for one.

Comment: Well in that case you need to rethink your entire approach to this, since what you want isn't possible.